# Rails CSV Import - File name too long @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So my import method has the following in the OccupantsController:

```
def import
 @occupant = Occupant::Import.run(params[:file].path, params[:training_event_id]).result
 if @occupant.errors.empty?
  flash[:notice] = "Imported"
 else
  flash[:notice] = "You have failed this import"
 end
end
```

Then in my Operations > Occupant > Import I have the following:

```
class Occupant
class Import < Operation
require 'csv'

def call(file, training_event_id)
  csv_text = File.read(file)
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text).to_s
  binding.pry
  list_occo = CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
    occupant = Occupant.new
    occupant.training_event_id = row[training_event_id]
    occupant.account_number = row['Account Number']
    occupant.first_name = row['First Name']
    occupant.last_name = row['Last Name']
    occupant.email = row['Email']
    occupant.hotel = row['Hotel']
    occupant.two_beds = row['Two Beds']
    occupant.company_id = row['Company ID']
    occupant.student_id = row['Student ID']
    occupant.address = row['Address']
    occupant.address_2 = row['Address 2']
    occupant.city = row['City']
    occupant.state = row['State']
    occupant.zip = row['Zip']
    occupant.phone = row['Phone']
    occupant.cancellation_agree = row['Cancellation Agree']
    occupant.share = row['Share']
    occupant.roommate = row['Roommate']
    occupant.check_in = row['Check In']
    occupant.check_out = row['Check Out']
    occupant.to_s
    validate_file = check_file(occupant)
    occupant.save if validate_file
  end
  list_occo
  binding.pry
end
```

This results in

> Errno::ENAMETOOLONG (File name too long @ rb_sysopen - [["Account Number", "First Name",etc

I originally had in my import method and call method respectively:

```
Occupant::Import.run(params[:file], params[:training_event_id])

list_occo = CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
```

However this was causing the same issue. So I thought I could just break these up and do the csv_text to handle the read and then do a parse on the file read and then convert to a string. No go.

I've also tried updating the params to do [:file].read and in the call method to use just file. Same issue.

Now if I do:

```
Occupant::Import.run(params[:file].path, params[:training_event_id]).result

list_occo = CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
```

With this combination, no errors until I try to call on another method for validation on the files. Except...it's not generating anything.

How do I read through the file with avoiding the file name too long?

EDIT:

I've also tried in the import method:

```
Occupant::Import.run(params[:file].path, params[:training_event_id]).result
```

Then in the call method:

```
url_data = open(file).read()
csv_data = url_data.parse_csv.to_s
CSV.foreach(csv_data, headers: true) do |row|
```

This ends up with:

> Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the content of the file to the `CSV.foreach` method, it expects a path to a file, not the actual content. The correct form would be `list_occo = CSV.foreach(the_path_of_the_file, headers: true) do |row|`.

I guess you can use something similar to what you already have with this:

```
csv_text = File.read(file_path)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text).to_s
```

I guess, if you remove the `to_s` call, `CSV.parse(csv_text)` gives you an array of rows, just do `csv.each do |row|` after that.

EDOT: correct use of `CSV.parse` is:

```
csv_text = File.read(file_path)
CSV.parse(csv_text) do |row|
  ...
end
```

Comment: So if I do csv_text and then the csv and then change CSV.foreach to simply csv.each I end up with no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String. So then I update the import to do [:file].path. Which results in NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00007fda98100548>)

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the `.each` call on the return value of `CSV.parse`. You can just do `CSV.parse(csv_text) do |row|` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-A+Line+at+a+Time

Comment: csv_text = File.read(file)
CSV.parse(csv_text, headers:true) do |row|
And simply having a params of [:file]. Results in no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String

Comment: If `file` is already an UploadedFile you can read it with file.read, you don't need to use File.read method https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-read

Comment: Yeah when I do CSV.foreach(file.read, headers: true) do |row| I'm getting the file name too long.

Comment: As I said, `CSV.foreach` expects a file path, not a string with the file's content. Use `file.path` as the parameter or use `CSV.parse(file.read) do |row|`. You should really read the documentation of the methods you are using so you know what do they return and what are you allowed to use as the arguments. I already linked you both Ruby's CSV docs and Rails' UploadedFile docs.